# Работа с Win32API (user32;gdi32) на C#

Tags: c#, winapi

Помогите функционалом библиотек Win32API (user32;gdi32)... 
Задание: В заданной пользователем области экрана поменять цвета пикселей на оттенки серого.

Вроде все просто, при клике берем начальное положение мыши при отпускании кнопки конечное. Высчитываем высоту, ширину и просто закрашиваем функцией SetPixel().

Внутри программы эвенты мыши просчитывать легко, а вот со всей системой (экраном), чет не могу понять.

Comment: Функционал библиотек в самих библиотеках, помогать тут нечего. Вопрос не понятен.

Comment: Я считаю заголовок вопроса нужно поменять. Всётаки работа понятие обширное, хотя бы "Перехват мыши (системный hook) на с#"

Answer (score 1):

Воспользоваться глобальным Hook перехватом ["Low-Level Mouse Hook in C#"](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/toub/2006/05/03/low-level-mouse-hook-in-c/)

```
class InterceptMouse
{
    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc, GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_LBUTTONDOWN == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));
            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.pt.x + ", " + hookStruct.pt.y);
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    private const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14;

    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201,
        WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202,
        WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200,
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A,
        WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204,
        WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public uint mouseData;
        public uint flags;
        public uint time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```